# How to export Nvd3 charts to jpeg or png format

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

Is there any better or easy way to export nvD3 chart to jpeg or png image format?
I tried Javascript SVG parser and renderer on Canvas by using http://code.google.com/p/canvg/
But in some cases (may be due to large size or greater resolution) the export option not working.

Comment: Better ask howto export SVG to png, because nvd3 might not be known by all SVG experts.

Comment: Have you seen [this project](https://github.com/shawnbot/d3-to-png)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for your above suggestion.

I was trying to import (nvd3)svg images using https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng
Here is some sample code:
<svg id="chart-svg" height="100%" width="100%"/>

function printPNG() {
 saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("chart-svg"), "diagram.png", 3);
}

But the problem is only left corner part of the chart is coming when i am trying to save/import.
Please suggest ..

Comment: I tried the saveSVGAsPng plugin and it works perfectly in chrome but am getting a DOM exception message when trying in Safari. I also tried canvg and it renders the svg as a canvas perfectly, but when I try to get the DataURI, it sends across a security exception!

Comment: @user3172663 what finally worked for you?

Comment: @Dinesh i left the option at https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng but this was not the best as there was some issue with some browsers.So i think the best solution would be go for d3Export http://d3export.housegordon.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to PNG and maintain CSS integrity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394041/convert-svg-to-png-and-maintain-css-integrity)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to support all browsers including IE/safari you'll have to implement that server side. I tried a lot but couldn't find a foolproof way to achieve 100% browser compatibility using only js. Canvg and saveSvgAsPng won't help you beyond firefox/chrome.

See how highcharts doing that as a fallback option http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server