# How Can I Download The Browser Generated Svg To Png Or Pdf Using Java Script Or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on an application where i need to show the data in graph's like(line,bar,scatter,..etc)
I want to give an option to user to download the Image(i.e. Graph) to PNG or PDF?

How can i achive this?

I am using nvd3 Charts to generate the Graphs..

Thaks for the help in Advance.

Comment: [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) provide [getImageURI()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) and are easy to use

Comment: Does nvd3 Charts have an export option? If you can export the data to a pdf/png in base64 encoded string or blob/binary array, then yes.

Comment: Encode base64 and store in a [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) as the `href` of a link.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043376/how-to-export-nvd3-charts-to-jpeg-or-png-format

Comment: @–WhiteHat..but I am working with the Nvd3Charts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following URl Resolves My Question..For your reference here i am posting the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/sbrickner/5VZvL/

Thanks`e`