# Dark filled Links being displayed when downloading d3 hierarchical edge bundling visualization as PNG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, png

I have created a D3 hierarchical edge bundling visualization.When i download this visualization as PNG,the links in downloaded image are filled with dark color which is not displayed in actual visualization.
Downloaded image is [image: Downloaded image]

Actual visualization being displayed is
[image: Actual visualization]

How to get the same visualization in downloaded image.
My current code is:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            .node {
              font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
            .link {
              stroke: steelblue;
              stroke-opacity: .4;
              fill: none;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            var classes=[
{"name":"a","size":3938,"imports":["b","f"]},
{"name":"b","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"c","size":3938,"imports":["a"]},
{"name":"d","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"e","size":3938,"imports":[]},
{"name":"f","size":3938,"imports":[]}


];
                    var diameter = 700,
                        radius = diameter / 2,
                        innerRadius = radius - 120;
                    var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
                        .size([360, innerRadius]);

                    var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

                    var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
                        .interpolate("bundle")
                        .tension(.85)
                        .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
                        .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

                    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("id","networkSvg")
                        .attr("width", diameter)
                        .attr("height", diameter)
                      .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");



                      var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
                          links = packageImports(nodes);

                      svg.selectAll(".link")
                          .data(bundle(links))
                        .enter().append("path")
                          .attr("class", "link")
                          .attr("d", line);

                      svg.selectAll(".node")
                          .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
                        .enter().append("g")
                          .attr("class", "node")
                          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
                        .on("mouseover", function(d){
                          d3.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "black");
                          d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke", "steelblue");
                          colorSource(d.name);

                          d.imports.forEach(function(name){
                            colorTarget(name);
                            colorOutgoingLink(d.name, name);
                          });

                          d.parent.children.forEach(function(data){
                              if(data.imports.indexOf(d.name)>-1)
                              {
                                colorTarget(data.name);
                                colorIncomingLink(data.name, d.name);
                              }
                          });
                        })
                        .on("mouseout",function(d)
                        {
                          d3.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "black");
                          d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke", "steelblue");

                        }) 
                        .append("text")
                          .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 8 : -8; })
                          .attr("dy", ".31em")
                          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                          .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; })
                          .text(function(d) { return d.key; });


                    // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.

                    function packageHierarchy(classes) {
                      var map = {};
                      function find(name, data) {
                        var node = map[name], i;
                        if (!node) {
                          node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
                          if (name.length) {
                            node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
                            node.parent.children.push(node);
                            node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
                          }
                        }
                        return node;
                      }
                      classes.forEach(function(d) {
                        find(d.name, d);
                      });
                      return map[""];
                    }


                    // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
                    function packageImports(nodes) {
                      var map = {},
                          imports = [];
                      // Compute a map from name to node.
                      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                        map[d.name] = d;
                      });
                      // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
                      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
                          imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
                        });
                      });
                      return imports;
                    }

                    function colorIncomingLink(src,tgt){
                      var link = d3.selectAll(".link")[0].filter(function(d){
                        return (d3.select(d).data()[0][0].name == src && d3.select(d).data()[0][2].name == tgt);
                      });
                      d3.selectAll(link).style("stroke", "green");
                    }

                    function colorOutgoingLink(src,tgt){
                      var link = d3.selectAll(".link")[0].filter(function(d){
                        return (d3.select(d).data()[0][0].name == src && d3.select(d).data()[0][2].name == tgt);
                      });
                      d3.selectAll(link).style("stroke", "red");
                    }

                    function colorTarget(name){
                      //iterate through all teh dom and get the DOM which has the data
                      var node = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].filter(function(d){
                        return d3.select(d).data()[0].name == name;
                      });
                      d3.selectAll(node).style("fill", "red");
                    }

                    function colorSource(name){
                      //iterate through all teh dom and get teh DOM which has the data
                      var node = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].filter(function(d){
                        return d3.select(d).data()[0].name == name;
                      });
                      d3.selectAll(node).style("fill", "green");
                    }

                     function download()
                    {

                        img = new Image(),
                        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
                        svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(document.getElementById('networkSvg'));

                    img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);

                    // You could also use the actual string without base64 encoding it:
                    //img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + svgStr;

                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

                    var w=2000;
                    var h=2000;

                    canvas.width = w;
                    canvas.height = h;
                    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0,w,h);

                    var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


                var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
                    dlLink.download = "down";
                    dlLink.href = imgURL;
                    dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = ["image/png", dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

                    document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
                    dlLink.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(dlLink);


                    }
                    </script>
                    <button onclick="download()">Download</button>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is because you are not considering the CSS on export you can give this a try  1st answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394041/convert-svg-to-png-and-maintain-css-integrity

Comment: @Cyril i tried setting the fill property,stroke and opacity using d3.selectAll(".links").style("fill","none")...but on doing this ....on clicking the download button....download failed shows up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Cyril, you can set all styles through d3 rather than using external style sheet.

Here is the working code snippet.

```js
var classes = [{
    "name": "a",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": ["b", "f"]
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": []
  }, {
    "name": "c",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": ["a"]
  }, {
    "name": "d",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": []
  }, {
    "name": "e",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": []
  }, {
    "name": "f",
    "size": 3938,
    "imports": []
  }


];
var diameter = 700,
  radius = diameter / 2,
  innerRadius = radius - 120;
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([360, innerRadius]);

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
  .interpolate("bundle")
  .tension(.85)
  .radius(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .angle(function(d) {
    return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("id", "networkSvg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .style("background-color","white")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");


var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
  links = packageImports(nodes);

svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(bundle(links))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke", "steelblue")
  .style("stroke-opacity", .4)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return !n.children;
  }))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .style("font", "11px Helvetica Neue Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "black");
    d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke", "steelblue");
    colorSource(d.name);

    d.imports.forEach(function(name) {
      colorTarget(name);
      colorOutgoingLink(d.name, name);
    });

    d.parent.children.forEach(function(data) {
      if (data.imports.indexOf(d.name) > -1) {
        colorTarget(data.name);
        colorIncomingLink(data.name, d.name);
      }
    });
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".node").style("fill", "black");
    d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke", "steelblue");

  })
  .append("text")
  .style("stroke","black")
  .attr("dx", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? 8 : -8;
  })
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  });


// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.

function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name],
      i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {
        name: name,
        children: []
      };
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }
  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });
  return map[""];
}


// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
    imports = [];
  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });
  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push({
        source: map[d.name],
        target: map[i]
      });
    });
  });
  return imports;
}

function colorIncomingLink(src, tgt) {
  var link = d3.selectAll(".link")[0].filter(function(d) {
    return (d3.select(d).data()[0][0].name == src && d3.select(d).data()[0][2].name == tgt);
  });
  d3.selectAll(link).style("stroke", "green");
}

function colorOutgoingLink(src, tgt) {
  var link = d3.selectAll(".link")[0].filter(function(d) {
    return (d3.select(d).data()[0][0].name == src && d3.select(d).data()[0][2].name == tgt);
  });
  d3.selectAll(link).style("stroke", "red");
}

function colorTarget(name) {
  //iterate through all teh dom and get the DOM which has the data
  var node = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].filter(function(d) {
    return d3.select(d).data()[0].name == name;
  });
  d3.selectAll(node).style("fill", "red");
}

function colorSource(name) {
  //iterate through all teh dom and get teh DOM which has the data
  var node = d3.selectAll(".node")[0].filter(function(d) {
    return d3.select(d).data()[0].name == name;
  });
  d3.selectAll(node).style("fill", "green");
}

function download() {

  img = new Image(),
    serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
    svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(document.getElementById('networkSvg'));

  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgStr);

  // You could also use the actual string without base64 encoding it:
  //img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + svgStr;

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  var w = 2000;
  var h = 2000;

  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

  var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


  var dlLink = document.createElement('a');
  dlLink.download = "down";
  dlLink.href = imgURL;
  dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = ["image/png", dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

  document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
  dlLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dlLink);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
```